# Auto Sizing Two Text Views to display as much content as possible

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

There are two text views inside a linear layout with horizontal orientation.

LeftText | RightText

Objective is to make best use of the screen space and display both the text values as much as possible. If the text exceeds the textview size, they should be truncated with ellipsis. If one of them is short, the other one should expand to the remaining size.

For e.g.

1. Input - **Short | Short**
   Expected Output **Short | Short**
2. Input - **Short | LongLongLongLong**
   Expected Output **Short | Long...**
3. Input - **LongLongLongLong | Short**
   Expected Output **LongLong...|Short**
4. Input - **LongLongLongLong | LongLongLongLong**
   Expected Output **LongLong...|LongLong...**

I have tried to create a custom view AutoSizingTextLayout (extends LinearLayout) which consists of two custom Text Views with initial equal layout weight = 1. I have added a onDrawListener for the second Text View (one on the right). As soon as the second text view is done drawing, I adjust the weights depending on which text was truncated.

This logic works but not reliably. On some runs, it runs perfectly but most times, the first text view takes the entire screen.

I am pasting relevant part of my code below. Is there something that needs to be handled? Is there a more elegant solution? 
PS: This custom view is being used inside a list recycler view.

```
public class AutoSizingTextLayout extends LinearLayout implements 
AutoSizingTextView.AutoSizingTextViewDrawListener {

@BindView(R.id.start_text_view)
AutoSizingTextView mStartTextView;

@BindView(R.id.end_text_view)
AutoSizingTextView mEndTextView;

private volatile boolean adjusted = false;

//Constructors

@Override
public void onDraw() {
    if (!adjusted) {
        adjustWeights();
    }
}

public void setStartViewText(String startText) {
    mStartTextView.setText(startText);
}

public void setEndViewText(String endText) {
    adjusted = false;
    mEndTextView.setText(endText);
}

private void initView(AttributeSet attrs) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.auto_sizing_text_layout, this);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    mEndTextView.setDrawListener(this);
}

private void adjustWeights() {
    boolean startTextHasEllipses = hasEllipses(mStartTextView);
    boolean endTextHasEllipses = hasEllipses(mEndTextView);

    ArrayList<AutoSizingTextView> viewsToUpdate = new ArrayList<>();

    if (startTextHasEllipses && endTextHasEllipses) {
        //Both are truncated. Do nothing.
    } else if (startTextHasEllipses) {
        // Starting text is truncated. End text is not truncated. Give more weight to starting text.
        viewsToUpdate.add(mEndTextView);
    } else if (endTextHasEllipses) {
        // Starting text is not truncated. End text is truncated. Give more weight to ending text.
        viewsToUpdate.add(mStartTextView);
    } else {
        // Both are not truncated. Set it to wrap content.
        viewsToUpdate.add(mStartTextView);
        viewsToUpdate.add(mEndTextView);
    }
    updateView(viewsToUpdate);
}

private void updateView(List<AutoSizingTextView> viewsToUpdate) {
    for (AutoSizingTextView viewToUpdate : viewsToUpdate) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)
                viewToUpdate.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        params.weight = 0.0F;
        adjusted = true;
        viewToUpdate.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
    this.requestLayout();
}

private static boolean hasEllipses(TextView textView) {
    Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
    if (layout != null) {
        int lines = layout.getLineCount();
        if (lines > 0) {
            if (layout.getEllipsisCount(lines - 1) > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

//Custom Text View

```
class AutoSizingTextView extends 
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

private AutoSizingTextViewDrawListener mDrawListener;

//Constructors

public void setDrawListener(AutoSizingTextViewDrawListener drawListener) {
    mDrawListener = drawListener;
}

public interface AutoSizingTextViewDrawListener {
    void onDraw();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (mDrawListener != null) {
        mDrawListener.onDraw();
    }
}
}
```

//auto_sizing_text_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<AutoSizingTextView
    android:id="@+id/start_text_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"/>

<AutoSizingTextView
    android:id="@+id/end_text_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose following is the expected result.

[image]

I wrote a simple `ViewGroup` for this. Of course, it is not perfect. It just demonstrates that it is achievable. Modify this code accordingly. I have overridden the [`onLayout()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onLayout(boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method of the `ViewGroup` where I'm computing the required size of the subviews and laying out them accordingly. This `WeirdView` contains three `TextView`s for (left text, a separator, and a right text) respectively.

```
package com.example.abhinav.textviewexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by abhinav on 16/04/18.
 */

public class WeirdView extends ViewGroup {

    private TextView mLeftTV;
    private TextView mSeparatorTV;
    private TextView mRightTV;

    public WeirdView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public WeirdView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public WeirdView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        mLeftTV = new TextView(context);
        mSeparatorTV = new TextView(context);
        mRightTV = new TextView(context);

        mLeftTV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mSeparatorTV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mRightTV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        addView(mLeftTV);
        addView(mSeparatorTV);
        addView(mRightTV);
    }

    public TextView getLeftTextView() {
        return mLeftTV;
    }

    public TextView getSeparatorTextView() {
        return mSeparatorTV;
    }

    public TextView getRightTextView() {
        return mRightTV;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        final int childLeft = this.getPaddingLeft();
        final int childTop = this.getPaddingTop();
        final int childRight = this.getMeasuredWidth() - this.getPaddingRight();
        final int childBottom = this.getMeasuredHeight() - this.getPaddingBottom();
        final int availableWidth = childRight - childLeft;
        final int availableHeight = childBottom - childTop;

        mLeftTV.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(availableWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(availableHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
        mSeparatorTV.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(availableWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(availableHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
        mRightTV.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(availableWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(availableHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));

        // case: |blabla > blablabla         |
        // case: |blablablablablabla > bla   |
        // case: |bla > blablablablablablab..|
        if ((mLeftTV.getMeasuredWidth() + mSeparatorTV.getMeasuredWidth() + mRightTV.getMeasuredWidth() <= availableWidth)
                || (mLeftTV.getMeasuredWidth() <= availableWidth / 2)) {
            int left = childLeft;
            mLeftTV.layout(left, childTop, left + mLeftTV.getMeasuredWidth(), childBottom);
            left += mLeftTV.getMeasuredWidth();
            mSeparatorTV.layout(left, childTop, left + mSeparatorTV.getMeasuredWidth(), childBottom);
            left += mSeparatorTV.getMeasuredWidth();
            mRightTV.layout(left, childTop, childRight, childBottom);
            mRightTV.setWidth(childRight - left);
        }
        // case: |blablablablablabla.. > blab|
        else if (mRightTV.getMeasuredWidth() <= availableWidth / 2) {
            int left = childLeft;
            mLeftTV.layout(left, childTop, childRight - mSeparatorTV.getMeasuredWidth() - mRightTV.getMeasuredWidth(), childBottom);
            mLeftTV.setWidth(childRight - mSeparatorTV.getMeasuredWidth() - mRightTV.getMeasuredWidth() - left);
            left += mLeftTV.getWidth();
            mSeparatorTV.layout(left, childTop, mSeparatorTV.getMeasuredWidth(), childBottom);
            left += mSeparatorTV.getMeasuredWidth();
            mRightTV.layout(left, childTop, mRightTV.getMeasuredWidth(), childBottom);
        }
        // case: |blablabla.. > blablablabl..|
        else {
            int left = childLeft;
            mLeftTV.layout(left, childTop, left + availableWidth / 2 - mSeparatorTV.getMeasuredWidth() / 2, childBottom);
            mLeftTV.setWidth(availableWidth / 2 - mSeparatorTV.getMeasuredWidth() / 2);
            left += (availableWidth / 2 + mSeparatorTV.getMeasuredWidth() / 2);
            mSeparatorTV.layout(left, childTop, left + mSeparatorTV.getMeasuredWidth(), childBottom);
            left += mSeparatorTV.getMeasuredWidth();
            mRightTV.layout(left, childTop, childRight, childBottom);
            mRightTV.setWidth(childRight - left);
        }
    }
}
```